# visual studio c# classes and objects using multi form application using MDI

Tags: c#, windows, forms

My first post here although I've been an avid reader. My problem is a student registration system (no data binding, database) just simply add some papers and students with the ability to add students and papers via user forms.
An exercise in classes and multiple forms.
I have the classes and forms in my project and linked using MDI which has its problems. I can't seem to access the members in a form other than form1 (the parent) which isn't ideal as if I try to hide that the whole application shuts down.
Also I am having trouble adding a new entry to my list of students as an object from the student enrollment form I created.

Given the class:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int IdNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Dob { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public Student(int idNumber,     string name, string dob, int age, string address)
        {
            IdNumber = idNumber;
            Name = name;
            Dob = dob;
            Age = age;
            Address = address;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Student ID: " + IdNumber.ToString() + " Name: " + Name + " DOB: " + Dob.ToString() + " Age: " +
                   Age.ToString() + " Address: " + Address + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

Student list populated:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            myStudents.Add(new Student(123, "Andrew","3/05/1978",27,"123 home street"));
            myStudents.Add(new Student(124, "John", "17/02/1989", 26, "12 argus place"));
            myStudents.Add(new Student(125, "Steve", "12/05/1989", 34, "14 home road"));
            myStudents.Add(new Student(126, "Mary", "1/07/1972", 19, "66 blue street"));
            myStudents.Add(new Student(127, "Jane", "31/07/1975", 21, "64 green street"));
            foreach (Student s in myStudents)
            {
                txtBox_form1.Text = txtBox_form1.Text + s.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
```

Ideally I don't want to do this in Form1 as im using MDI parent form but can't seem to access the members after instantiating in an additional presentation form called 'admin' which is a child of the main MDI parent form, not sure why?

Here is what I am thinking, or a method call when the new student details are enter via a user form

```
private void bttnSubmit_Enroll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//this is for another test through constructor
           // Admin _admin = new Admin(txtBox_SName.Text);
          //  _admin.ShowDialog();
          //  _admin.Show();
            Student newStudent = new Student(int.Parse(txtBox_StudentID.Text), txtBox_SName.Text, txtBox_StudentDOB.Text, int.Parse(txtBox_Age.Text), txtBox_StudentAddress.Text);
```

how to create a new object from user input and add it to my list is what I'm trying to figure out.

Any advice/suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks 
Andrew

Comment: I do not understand what you're trying to ask

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get the student information from a form. When submit the new student is created as a new object of the class Student and added to the list.